# How can I avoid typing a module name every time in rspec?

Tags: ruby

I am testing a class within my module 'RecipientMatcher'.

It is very cumbersome to have to keep typing the prefaced name 'RecipientMatcher' in front of all of my classes.  I was wondering if there is a better way?

Today's code:

```
ocr_text = 'Jim Baker & Co'
recipient_matches = [
RecipientMatcher::RecipientMatchFound.new(build(:group), RecipientMatcher::MatchObject.new(nil,'Jim'), ocr_text, ocr_text.match(/Jim/)),
RecipientMatcher::RecipientMatchFound.new(build(:group), RecipientMatcher::MatchObject.new(nil, 'Jim Baker & Co'), ocr_text, ocr_text.match(/Jim Baker & Co/)),
RecipientMatcher::RecipientMatchFound.new(build(:group), RecipientMatcher::MatchObject.new(nil, 'Jim Baker'), ocr_text, ocr_text.match(/Jim Baker/)),
]

section_meta_data = RecipientMatcher::PossibleRecipientsCalculator.determine_primary_recipients_in_section(recipient_matches)
primary_recipients = section_meta_data.primary_recipients

expect(true).to eq(true)
```

It would be ideal if I could just write this:

```
RecipientMatcher.magic_method do
    ocr_text = 'Jim Baker & Co'
    recipient_matches = [
    ::RecipientMatchFound.new(build(:group), ::MatchObject.new(nil,'Jim'), ocr_text, ocr_text.match(/Jim/)),
    ::RecipientMatchFound.new(build(:group), ::MatchObject.new(nil, 'Jim Baker & Co'), ocr_text, ocr_text.match(/Jim Baker & Co/)),
    ::RecipientMatchFound.new(build(:group), ::MatchObject.new(nil, 'Jim Baker'), ocr_text, ocr_text.match(/Jim Baker/)),
    ]

    section_meta_data = ::PossibleRecipientsCalculator.determine_primary_recipients_in_section(recipient_matches)
    primary_recipients = section_meta_data.primary_recipients

    expect(true).to eq(true)
end
```

Comment: What are you optimizing for? Reducing repetition? Shorter lines? Readability? Maintainability?

Comment: All of the above: shorter lines, reducing repetition, maintainability!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RSpec's [described_class](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/metadata/described-class), provided you supply the class as the argument to the main `describe` block, as follows:

```
RSpec.describe RecipientMatcher::RecipientMatchFound do
  it 'whatever' do
    described_class.new(...)
  end
end
```

Alternatively you may define a variable (or a `let` in RSpec) for the class, e.g. something like this:

```
let(:match_found) { RecipientMatcher::RecipientMatchFound }
let(:match_object) { RecipientMatcher::MatchObject }

it 'whatever' do
  match_found.new(build(:group), match_object.new(...))
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Perennially, I'd just say write it out. A little more typing but pretty easy reading.

That said, here's what I'd suggest:

Method 1: shorten it by assigning the module to a variable

```
rm = RecipientMatcher
rm::RecipientMatchFound.new(...)
...
```

or even further down to the individual nested classes

```
match_found = RecipientMatcher::RecipientNotFound
match_obj = RecipientMatcher::MatchObject

match_found.new(...)
```

---

Method 2: wrap your constructions in a helper method for each commonly used segment

```
def build_match(str)
  RecipientMatcher::RecipientMatchFound.new(build(:group), RecipientMatcher::MatchObject.new(nil,str), ocr_text, ocr_text.match(/#{str}/))
end

recipient_matches = [
  build_match('Jim'),
  build_match(...),
  ...
]
```

or in loops

```
recipient_matches = ['Jim', 'Baker & Co', ...].map{|str| build_match(str)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always create an alias, it's really easy:

```
RecipientMatchFound = RecipientMatcher::RecipientMatchFound
MatchObject = RecipientMatcher::MatchObject

ocr_text = 'Jim Baker & Co'
recipient_matches = [
  RecipientMatchFound.new(build(:group), MatchObject.new(nil,'Jim'), ocr_text, ocr_text.match(/Jim/)),
  RecipientMatchFound.new(build(:group), MatchObject.new(nil, 'Jim Baker & Co'), ocr_text, ocr_text.match(/Jim Baker & Co/)),
  RecipientMatchFound.new(build(:group), MatchObject.new(nil, 'Jim Baker'), ocr_text, ocr_text.match(/Jim Baker/)),
]

section_meta_data = RecipientMatcher::PossibleRecipientsCalculator.determine_primary_recipients_in_section(recipient_matches)
primary_recipients = section_meta_data.primary_recipients

expect(true).to eq(true)
```

Though refactoring a bit more you can really boil this down by applying the tried-and-true method called *Don't Repeat Yourself* or DRY:

```
recipient_matches = [
  'Jim',
  'Jim Baker & Co',
  'Jim Baker'
].map do |name|
  RecipientMatchFound.new(
    build(:group),
    MatchObject.new(nil, name), ocr_text, ocr_text.match(name)
  )
end
```

Try and think about Ruby programs in terms of data transformation. You can often start with something simple, like this array of names, and build out exactly the structures you want step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea. Instead of

```
RecipientMatcher::RecipientMatchFound
```

you could use

```
magic_resolver('RecipientMatchFound')
```

where it is defined as an RSpec-helper:

```
def magic_resolver(class_name)
  "RecipientMatcher::#{class_name}".constantize
end
```

Comment: That's certainly one way to tackle this problem, but it does seem like overkill. All that's needed here is a simple alias.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this today (using `ruby` 2.7.2 and `rspec` v3.6.0) while trying to solve the same problem. I have a gem with module `Foo::Bar` wherein are defined all the gem's classes and I don't want to be typing out the `Foo::Bar::` prefix in all my specs.

I tried editing spec_helper.rb:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Foo::Bar
  ...
end
```

but that didn't work.

Ultimately, adding

```rb
include Foo::Bar
```

to `spec_helper.rb` *above* the

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
...
```

block allowed me to reference classes without the prefix, such as:

```rb
RSpec.describe Baz do; end
```

instead of

```rb
RSpec.describe Foo::Bar::Baz do; end
```